# Maximum number of the same word in an English language sequence (punctuation allowed)

Tags: english

An old  school boy riddle is how to to  have  5  x  "and" in sequence and yet  still make grammatical sense. The answer is that a man saw a sign advertising Dogs and Cats for sale. He commented that the  sign was badly laid out because there was too much space between Dogs and "and" and "and" and Cats.  = 5 x "and"
QUESTION: Can you make grammatically correct sequence with more than  5 x the  same word (not necessarily "and") ? If so, what is the maximum number of times of that word in sequence? 
NOTE:  By "sequence" I do not mean a single sentence. The "sequence" can be any number of consecutive sentences (and/or phrases) which themselves may include  as many punctuation and quotation marks as  you like as long as the whole "sequence" is correct grammatically.

Comment: By the looks of it, the sentence is grammatically incorrect, at least for me. The 5 ands in question isn't correct. The original sign was "Dogs and Cats for sale" , and the man said "....Dogs and "and" and "and" and Cats" thereby inserting an extra "and" in the original sentence. It should have been "...Dogs and "and" and Cats". The sentence the man was referring to would be "....Dogs and and Cats for sale" which isn't what you mentioned earlier.

Comment: But welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE). Please Clarify Your Question, Because I may be dumb at times :P

Comment: @R.D I disagree, the man is saying that there is too much space between Dogs and the word *and*, **and** between the word *and* and Cats. Or Dogs and *and* **and** *and* and Cats.

Comment: @Keelhaul makes sense! That comma makes all the difference. Without it, it seemed a bit messy.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate purportedly because the other question had an answer that answered this question. But it doesn’t - none of the answers there fits here. I question question closure.

Answer (score 5):

I quite like the one about the two guys comparing their grammar exam answers:

> John, while Pete had had "had", had had "had had".

Or to take it to ridiculousness: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher)

Comment: Yes . Thanks !  Using  "had" in that way  is  what I had (no pun intended ! ) as the   best answer.  The  "had / had had"   series  can be continued  almost forever (but I didn't  realize  that  even  THAT is now  on  Wikipedia ) .

Answer (score 4):

You can add the word

> Buffalo

an arbitrary number of times and it's always grammatically correct.

Because

> Buffalo can be a modifier (something from Buffalo, NY), a noun (the animal) or a verb (to intimidate)

e.g.

> Buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo
>
>  or, animals from Buffalo, NY intimidate other animals from the same city.

See

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

Comment: Please Explain What You Mean?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say you can come up with infinitely long series of "and" if you wish so:

> For instance, in your example with 5 "and", I find there is too much space between "Dogs" and "and" and "and" and ""and"" and ""and"" and "and" and "and" and ""and"" and ""and"" and "and" and "and" and Cats.
>  So, here I made **21 "and"**, but one more iteration and you could come up with 85. The exact formula seems to be **4n + 1 "and"** with **n** the number of "and" in the previous iteration.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you can make a grammatical sentence with both "and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and" and "and and and and...

Answer (score 0):

You need a word with different meanings. It could for example be a name;

> You can use the word/name *Will*.
>  You can say for example: *Will Will tell his friend Willy, that he will visit his cousin William or will he just go.*

You can also use the same name for all characters but thats really confusing.

> You can say for example: *Will Will tell his friend Will, that he will visit his cousin Will or will he just go.*

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE! I believe the question is about the longest continuous sequence of the same word.